# How can I get user question from a view that already has a slug

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to get a user question from `public_profile` view that uses slug to get user profile information, and now I wanted to get user question in the `public_profile` view that uses slug, but it gives me `Page not found (404)` error. I want a users to be able to see other user question in their profile page. How can I solve this problem to get users question when someone visited their profile page?

Question model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False) 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.title)
```

The view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def public_profile(request, slug):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, slug=slug)
    questions = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug)
    number_of_likes = Like.objects.filter(post__user=request.user).count()
    try:
        number_of_likes = Like.objects.filter(post__user=profile.user).count()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        number_of_likes = None
    context = {
        'profile':profile,
        'number_of_likes':number_of_likes,
        'questions':questions
    }
    return render(request, 'public_profile.html', context)
```

my template:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
           <div class="col">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item">{{question.title}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

urls:

```
    path('userProfile/<slug:slug>/', views.public_profile, name='Public_Profile'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the following line from

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, slug=slug)
```

to

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
```

Most likely what you want is to use the slug to fetch the `Question` and not the `User Profile`.